# How to include files in the loop via ajax

Tags: plugin-development, loop, ajax, include

I create plugin and I need to include multiple files via ajax.
When I don't use loop this code work:

```
include_once( trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . 'sections/a.php' );
```

When I try to use loop this code don't work and I don't know why:

```
include_once( trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . 'sections/' . $section['id'] . '.php' );
```

Please help.

Full code:

```
class MyPlugin_Admin {

    private $plugin_name;
    private $version;

    public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_myplugin_ui', array( $this, 'myplugin_ui' ) );
    }

    function myplugin_ui() {

        $sections = array(
            array( 'id' => 'a', 'title' => __( 'A', 'myplugin' ) ),
            array( 'id' => 'b', 'title' => __( 'B', 'myplugin' ) ),
            array( 'id' => 'c', 'title' => __( 'C', 'myplugin' ) ),
        );

    ?>

    <div id="myplugin_wrap">

        <nav id="myplugin_nav">
            <ul>
            <?php foreach ( $sections as $section ) : ?>
                <li><a data-nav="<?php echo $section['id'];?>" href="#"><?php echo $section['title'];?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="myplugin_sections">
        <?php foreach ( $sections as $section ) : ?>
            <div id="tabs-<?php echo $section['id'];?>" class="hidable wrap" style="display: none;">
                <?php include_once( trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . 'sections/' . $section['id'] . '.php' ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php wp_die();
    }
}
```

Comment: `include_once` will only include... once.

Comment: I have "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) - ...wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=myplugin_ui".